# ggvenn::ggvenn() Venn diagram out of margin

Tags: r, venn-diagram

**Question**

I made a Venn plot using ggvenn::ggvenn(), but the label of a group is out of the canvas margin.

**Code and Results**

That is a simple example showing what the problem is.

```
pacman::p_load(dplyr, ggvenn)

my_dt <- tibble(
  value = c(1 : 8),
  long_group = c(TRUE,  FALSE, TRUE,  TRUE,  FALSE, TRUE,  FALSE, TRUE),
  group_a = c(TRUE,  FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,  FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE),
  group_b = c(TRUE,  TRUE,  FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,  TRUE),
  group_c = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,  TRUE,  FALSE, FALSE)
)
ggvenn(my_dt)
```

The result is that the label for the group "long_group" doesn't show up completely (we can only see a "g_group"). I tried changing the margin by `par(mar = c(2, 2, 2, 2))` before running the `ggvenn(my_dt)` but it didn't work.

[Venn diagram generated by the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdXYw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the helpful reproducible example.

You can use a combination of `set_name_size` and `position` to adjust the margins. I don't think `par` and `mar` will work because those are for R base graphics, not `ggplot2` functions.

`set_name_size` makes the fonts for the groups larger or smaller

`position` uses a set of `position` functions that allow you to adjust the positioning of the plot objects.

```
ggplot(my_dt, aes(A = long_group , B = group_a, C = group_b, D = group_c)) + 
      geom_venn(set_name_size = 6, position = position_nudge(x=-0.1))
```

[image: Venn diagram with position nudged]

Answer (score 0):

I had your same issue and found a nice and quick solution.
Since ggvenn builds a ggplot object, you can prevent the clipping of margins as following:

```
ggvenn(my_dt)+coord_cartesian(clip="off")
```

Here the outcome with your reproducible example:
[ggvenn_mydt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v262R.png)